# Adding multiple grid tables to pdf

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create a pdf which has multiple graphs and multiple grid.tables, is it possible to add multiple grid table to separate pages?

I have tried something like this:

```
AllPlots_CRP = list(plot1, plot2)

pdf(file=paste("TEST1_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf"), width=15,height=10)

c(AllPlots, grid.table(tab1), grid.table(tab2)

dev.off()
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `plot.new()` before each call to `grid.table()`

```r
pdf(file=paste("TEST1_", Sys.Date(), ".pdf"), width=15,height=10)
plot1
plot2
plot.new()
grid.table(df, theme = mytheme, rows = NULL)
plot.new()
grid.table(tab2)
dev.off()
```